# A more specific word for this type of illegal campaign

Tags: word-request

There's an election crime in Brazil that consists of asking people to vote for a specific candidate and try to persuade them to vote for a specific candidate at the time of voting at the voting place.

Is that a thing in the US or other English speaking countries?

Do you have a word/phrase for this?

Maybe illegal campaign. But this is a very specific situation/crime.

Comment: Your meaning is not clear. In most democratic countries, it is not illegal to ask or encourage people to vote for any candidate, (all the parties will do this) and once a voter is at the voting station, it's a secret who they vote for, so how exactly would this work.

Comment: Do you mean people wait at the voting station and attempt to make voters change their minds about who to vote for?

Comment: Yes. When people are waiting in line to vote.

Comment: What do you call it in Brazil?  Where there is a culturally specific action, or a law specific to one particular country, it tends not to have much meaning in another.  It's like there is no word for "jaywalking" in British English (except the borrowed term from American English) because "jaywalking" isn't an offence in England.

Comment: Boca de urna. Literally ballot box mouth.

Comment: I don't think there is an English word for that because that is not generally a crime.  [Here in the US, we have laws about things like how close you can stand to the poll and try to influence people](https://www.ncsl.org/research/elections-and-campaigns/electioneering.aspx), but there is no general name for those laws that I know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English is quite happy to borrow words.  This is a culturally specific practice, and so there is no specific term in English.  You can borrow and define.

So if you are writing an essay you might write:

> Pablo was accused of *boca de urna* (illegally distributing political pamphlets on election day) and arrested. The police found no evidence of *boca de urna* and so released him later that day.

Once it is defined, you can use the borrowed term.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, only registered voters and official supervisors are allowed in 'polling stations'. It is illegal for anyone to 'canvass' for an election candidate inside a polling station, and within a circular area (the prescribed area) of radius 250 metres centred on a polling station.

The Act of Parliament that currently regulates the operation of polling stations is the Polling Stations (Regulation) Act 2007.

'Canvass' is defined in the Act as:

> (a)   the promotion or distribution of any literature associated with
> election candidates, political parties or associated organisations;
>
> (b)   the use of audio equipment, whether stationary or mobile, for
> the propagation of messages relating to an election; or
>
> (c)   oral communication for the purpose of eliciting voting
> intentions or influencing the casting of a vote.

The Act says

> It shall be an offence to engage in campaigning activity within a
> prescribed area around a polling station on the day of a relevant
> election at any time during the period in which the polling station is
> open.

[Parliamentary Bill](https:///https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm200607/cmbills/027/2007027.pdf)

Someone suspecting of breaking this law would be prosecuted for 'an offence under the  Polling Stations (Regulation) Act 2007'.

Offences under this legislation are sufficiently rare in the UK that no slang or casual word for this activity has arisen.